# RecyclerView with FloatingActionButton Selection Not Happening

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I am working on a `RecylerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireActivity(),  2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

Unable to change color and mark selection of items except the third item in the first row, all other items remain unselected. But I can see the correct Item name and Id selected when logging inside the `setOnClickListener`, only problem is marking selection not happening for other items.

Please see the image below.

[image]

See my adapter code

```
package com.example.ui.home.collection.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.abc.R
import com.example.abc.data.network.responses.success.CollectionCustomersResponse
import com.example.abc.databinding.ItemCollectionTypeBinding
import com.example.abc.ui.home.collection.adapter.viewHolder.ItemViewHolder


class ItemAdapter(
    private val items: List<CollectionCustomersResponse.Items>,
    private val context: Context,
    private var onItemClicked: ((item: CollectionCustomersResponse.Items) -> Unit)
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var binding: ItemCollectionTypeBinding
    private var selectedItemID :Long = 0

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ItemViewHolder {
        binding = ItemCollectionTypeBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)

        return ItemViewHolder(binding)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        val selectedColorState = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.resources.getColor(R.color.main_color))
        val unSelectedColorState = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.resources.getColor(R.color.grey_shade))

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            setSelectedItemID(item.CustomerInventoryID)
            onItemClicked(item)
        }

        if (selectedItemID == item.CustomerInventoryID) {
            binding.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.item_selected1)
            binding.fab.backgroundTintList = selectedColorState
        } else {
            binding.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.item_unselected)
            binding.fab.backgroundTintList = unSelectedColorState
        }

        binding.tvItemName.setTextIsSelectable(true)

        holder.bind(item)
    }

    private fun setSelectedItemID (itemID: Long) {
        this.selectedItemID = itemID
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }



    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
}
```

My adapter item xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.abc.data.response.CollectionCustomersResponse.Items" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4sp">


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/item_unselected"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/grey_shade"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvItemName"
            android:layout_width="77sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@{item.itemName}"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fab"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/fab"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fab"
            tools:text="Bed Sheets" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Not sure what is wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It won't work because you are only keeping a track of a single item id i.e. the latest one would be saved due to `selectedItemID`. Use an `ArrayList` or any other `Collection` for multi-selection.

Comment: @Darshan  I don't want to multiple item selection as per my requirements.

Comment: Can you try `notifyItemChanged` instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: @Darshan I have tried not working.

Answer (score 0):

So first I see no need for the `selectedItemID` in this case 
All you have to make is to add a new variable to your model as a Boolean name it for example `isSelected` then when the fab is clicked you will check if it is selected or not then change the backgroundTintList like this

```
binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
if (item.isSelected){
                holder.fab.backgroundTintList = unSelectedColorState
                item.isSelected = false
            }else{
                holder.fab.backgroundTintList = selectedColorState
                item.isSelected = true
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with `Data Binding`. Implemented the whole adapter with `findViewById()` and it worked seamlessly.

```
package com.example.abc.ui.home.collection.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.example.abc.R
import com.example.abc.data.network.responses.success.CollectionCustomersResponse


class ItemAdapter(
    private val items: List<CollectionCustomersResponse.Items>,
    private val context: Context,
    private var onItemClicked: ((item: CollectionCustomersResponse.Items) -> Unit)
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var selectedItemID :Long = 0

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {

        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_collection_type, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        val selectedColorState = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.resources.getColor(R.color.main_color))
        val unSelectedColorState = ColorStateList.valueOf(context.resources.getColor(R.color.grey_shade))


        holder.fab.setOnClickListener {
            setSelectedItemID(item.CustomerInventoryID)
            onItemClicked(item)
        }


        if (selectedItemID == item.CustomerInventoryID) {
            holder.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.item_selected_4)
            holder.fab.backgroundTintList = selectedColorState
        } else {
            holder.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.item_unselected)
            holder.fab.backgroundTintList = unSelectedColorState
        }
        
        
        holder.tvItemName.text = item.ItemName
        holder.tvItemName.setTextIsSelectable(true)

    }

    private fun setSelectedItemID (itemID: Long) {
        this.selectedItemID = itemID
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val fab: FloatingActionButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fab)
        val tvItemName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size
}
```